# loose combination comparison

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, string-comparison

What would be the best aproach to compare 2 combinations?

My situation:

I currently have a `string string1 = "xxxxxx";`. Length is `6` characters. Each char values are either `0` or `1` or `x`. I need to compare this `string` to another `string` which has the eact same amount of characters but values are either `1` or `0`

- char `x` in first `string` means that the char value in second
  `string` can be anything
- char `0` in first `string` - only accepts `0` in second `string`
- char `1` in first `string` - only accepts `1` in second `string`

Here is a quick example:

```
string pattern = 'xxxxxx';
string test1 = '010101';
// pass

string pattern = '1xxxxx';
string test2 = '010101';
// not pass

string pattern = '0xxxxx';
string test3 = '010101';
// pass
```

I have made a function for it:

```
    public bool passCombination(string pattern, string combination)
    {
        bool combination_passed = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
        {
            char test_char = pattern[i];
            if (test_char != 'x' && combination[i] != test_char)
            {
                combination_passed = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return combination_passed;
    }
```

It's quite simple. Basically I am itterating `char` after `char`. If it's `x` then I don't care for value in second string. If it's other char - then compare.

Since it's a string based aproach I was thinking about other solution maybe? In my real scenario I have to perform about (~700k such checks * ~1.5 million times). And this very optimistic number :)

I was thinking about `regex` comparison or saving all combinations into `int[]` arrays and comparing them. Or perhaps there can be some magic done using `hashes`?

So it's at least 3 other options which *might* increase performance.. Can anyone suggest more performant solution?

**Edit:**

I did run the comparison tests. With old aproach I was getting 2.5 minutes of execution time and with the new aproach suggested below (accepted answer) - about 2 minutes. It is roughly `20%` performance increase.

Comment: I dont understand, why you compare all chars. If the first char in your patterm already decides over the success of your logic, you can skip the other 5

Comment: that's why there is a `break` in function

Comment: Simpler to return `false` on the first non-match, then return `true` at the end. Won't save you any cycles though, or at least not enough to care.

Comment: In the beginning of passCombination check that the length of pattern matches the length of combination

Comment: this will not be necessary.. upon data collection I always verify that the pattern is the same length as the stings I am comparing it to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure you actually need to optimize anything before you waste time writing overly-clever code to save cycles you can afford to waste.

But if you do need to optimize, you can always twiddle some bits. It's usually faster than looping through stuff and on the rare occasions when it isn't, it *looks* faster to anybody reading your code.

**Caveat:** If you'll never, or only rarely, be comparing any given "value" string more than once, there's no advantage to this approach, because compiling involves looping through the string anyway.

If you do have a performance issue, you could "compile" the pattern into two integers: One is a Pattern with `1` for every `1` and a `0` for every `0` or `x`; the other is a mask with a `0` for every `x` and a `1` for every `0` or `1`. You're wasting 26 bits per integer, but I won't tell anybody.

Then compile the values into ints: `1` for `1`, `0` for `0`.

Write a class that has those pattern/mask ints and a method to compare them to a value int. You would "precompile" the "values" and store them as integers instead of strings, or maybe a class that has an int property and a string property, if you'll be needing to display them (or you could write a function to convert those ints back into a string).

```
public class PatternMatcher
{
    public PatternMatcher(String pattern)
    {
        Pattern = CompilePattern(pattern);
        Mask = CompileMask(pattern);
    }

    #region Fields
    //  Could we save any cycles by making these fields instead of properties? 
    //  I think the optimizer is smarter than that. 
    public int Pattern { get; private set; }
    public int Mask { get; private set; }
    #endregion Fields

    public bool CheckValue(String value)
    {
        return CheckValue(CompileValue(value));
    }

    public bool CheckValue(int value)
    {
        //  a & b: Bitwise And
        //      Any bit that's "true" in both numbers is "true" in the result. 
        //      Any bit that's "false" in EITHER number is "false" in the result.

        //      11 & 11 == 11
        //      11 & 01 == 01
        //      11 & 10 == 10
        //      11 & 00 == 00

        //      01 & 11 == 01
        //      01 & 01 == 01
        //      01 & 10 == 00
        //      01 & 00 == 00

        //  So xx0011 -> 
        //      Pattern: 000011
        //      Mask:    001111
        //      Value    110011

        //  (110011 & 001111) == 000011
        //  (000011 & 001111) == 000011
        //
        //  000011 == 000011, so these two match. 

        return (value & Mask) == (Pattern & Mask);
    }

    public static int CompileMask(string patternString)
    {
        int mask = 0;
        int bitoffset = 0;

        //  For each character in patternString, set one bit in mask.
        //  Start with bit zero and move left one bit for each character.
        //  On x86, these bits are in reverse order to the characters in 
        //  the strings, but that doesn't matter. 
        foreach (var ch in patternString)
        {
            switch (ch)
            {
                //  If the pattern has a '0' or a '0', we'll be examining that 
                //  character in the value, so put a 1 at that spot in the mask.
                case '1':
                case '0':
                    //  a | b: Bitwise OR: If a bit is "true" in EITHER number, it's 
                    //  true in the result. So 0110 | 1000 == 1110.
                    //  a << b: Bitwise left shift: Take all the bits in a and move 
                    //  them leftward by 1 bit, so 0010 << 1 == 0100. 
                    //
                    //  So here we shift 1 to the left by some number of bits, and 
                    //  then set that bit in mask to 1. 
                    mask |= 1 << bitoffset;
                    break;

                //  If it's an 'x', we'll ignore that character in the value by 
                //  putting a 0 at that spot in the mask. 
                //  All the bits are zero already.
                case 'x':
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid pattern character: " + ch);
            }

            ++bitoffset;
        }

        return mask;
    }

    public static int CompilePattern(string patternString)
    {
        int pattern = 0;
        int bitoffset = 0;

        foreach (var ch in patternString)
        {
            //  For each character in patternString, set one bit in pattern.
            //  Start with bit zero and move left one bit for each character.
            switch (ch)
            {
                //  If the pattern has a 1, require 1 in the result.
                case '1':
                    pattern |= 1 << bitoffset;
                    break;

                //  For 0, require 0 in the result.
                case '0':
                    //  All the bits were zero already so don't waste time setting 
                    //  it to zero. 
                    break;

                //  Doesn't matter what we do for 'x', since it'll be masked out. 
                //  Just don't throw an exception on it. 
                case 'x':
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid pattern character: " + ch);
            }

            ++bitoffset;
        }

        return pattern;
    }

    public static int CompileValue(string valueString)
    {
        int value = 0;
        int bitoffset = 0;

        //  For each character in patternString, set one bit in mask.
        //  Start with bit zero and move left one bit for each character.
        foreach (var ch in valueString)
        {
            switch (ch)
            {
                //  If the value has a '1', have a 1 for that bit
                case '1':
                    value |= 1 << bitoffset;
                    break;

                //  If the value has a '0', leave a 0 for that bit
                //  All the bits were zero already.
                case '0':
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid pattern character: " + ch);
            }

            ++bitoffset;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Obviously you're wasting your time here if you can't precompile your values and store them as integers (and that's a big "if"). But if you can, you create one of those for each pattern, and use it 700k+ times in a loop. That's probably faster than looping over a string 700k+ times.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.. `Mask` and `Pattern` are always `0` after initialization with a pattern..

Comment: @Alex It's not you doing something wrong, it's my code. I just found that bug and I'm stepping through CompilePattern right now. More in a bit.

Comment: @Alex Derp, `mask |= 1 << bitoffset;`; it should be bitwise or. Bitwise anding zero against 1 doesn't do much. Must be having a low IQ day. Fixed and updated. Works for me now.

Comment: to answer your question - yes, I can make all kinds of modifications to data before starting my iterations :) And yes - they are reused multilpe times! So your solution fits perfectly fine! My issue now is, however, that your code is complicated! You have mentioned an IQ problem but I now starting to think that I am a kindergarden IQ level :D Thank you for the approach! I will try and make some performance tests maybe tomorrow and come back with results. And of course I need time to look up `bit` operators in `C#` as I have never used them before..

Comment: @Alex Not as complicated as it looks! The loops in those three "compile" methods are nearly identical. I'll add some comments. Do look up the bitwise operators though, they're fun, though you don't very often find them useful in C#. Used them a lot more doing old-fashioned Windows programming in C and C++.

Comment: Ed, I'm always intrigued by solutions requiring bitwise manipulation. Just to understand where this would be faster. It would only be when you have all the patterns given to you ahead of time so as to do the work before the loop, correct? Otherwise, I was thinking @Alex's solution would be the easiest way to go about doing this.

Comment: @JohnBustos Yes, it'd actually be slower if for every comparison you have to loop through the two strings separately instead of at the same time. It's only worthwhile if you can "precompile" everything in advance -- which often won't be the case, but by chance OP can do it that way. Which is nice, or I'd have wasted my time writing the code.

Comment: @JohnBustos In eight-bit ascii, in C/C++, you could play pointer/casting games and treat the strings as 64-bit integers, and never loop at all. That would be faster, period (if we had ham, we could have ham and eggs, if we had eggs). I don't know how you'd cast a .NET `String`'s buffer to a pair of unsigned longs; if pinvoke works, maybe you can. More likely you'd have to copy them into a new buffer.

Comment: Firstly, **LOL!!!** re: the Ham and Eggs!!! - Secondly, you truly did not waste your time coding and explaining - Like I said, seeing how this could be accomplished via bit manipulation is always great to see!!! - Thanks for writing the code and for the extra explanations!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Feels like the question might be missing some important information. For example, if the values are stored in a database, then a stored procedure should be faster than loading all of the data in memory.

On the other hand, loading the data into memory gives you more control over the **caching** (saving the already checked combinations in a hash table or array) and level of **parallelism** (checking different parts of the data on different processors or machines at the same time)

Also, if you are checking about a million patterns against about a million combinations, then there are better algorithms to get the current complexity from O(n^2) to something closer to O(n) http://bigocheatsheet.com/#chart

For the comparison of the pattern and combination, what you have now should be a tiny bit faster than converting the strings to integers. If you are comparing one pattern against multiple combinations, then what can speed it up a bit is if you save the positions that are not `x` and compare only them. For example:

```
foreach ( string pattern in patterns )
{
    // save the non x indexes
    var indexes = new List<int>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
        if (pattern[i] != 'x')
            indexes.Add(i);

    foreach ( string combination in combinations )
    {
        bool combination_passed = true;
        foreach (int i in indexes)
        {
            if (combination[i] != pattern[i])
            {
                combination_passed = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```